# How to interpret estimation (regression, discrete choice ) result?

Tags: regression, logistic, generalized-linear-model, choice-modeling

In a discrete choice model setting, 
lets say my model function is 
$U(x)= \beta_0+\beta_1X_1+\beta_2X_2+\beta_3X_3+\beta_4X4+\epsilon$

with 
independent variable $X_1$ has a value ranges from -2.5 to 2.5
$X_2$ is always positive
$X_3$ is always negative
and $X_4$ is binary dummy

In this case How can I interpret sign of variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sign of the variable tells you the impact on the choice proba P(Y=1) when you increase the independent variable by +1 unit. So basically if you find a positive effect for (X2) it means that increasing the level of X2 makes the option/product more likely to be selected. If you want to obtain similar effect but for a decrease in the variable, simply take its negative. If you variable is categorical (e.g., X2 = {Male; Female}) then the sign will tell you the effect of moving from the reference level (say Male) to the target one (Female).